# Angular 6 - mat-icon-rtl-mirror is not rendering the icon

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am implementing tree navigation using the documentation from the official angular material site. When using 'mat-icon-rtl-mirror' CSS class to render an icon, the browser is showing the name of the icon rather than the actual image.

```
<mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
      {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
</mat-icon>
```

The result I am getting is like this

[image]

When really it should be like this

[image]

I am also attaching my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {DemoMaterialModule} from '../material-module';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';

import {TreeChecklistExample} from './asset-navigation/asset-navigation';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TreeChecklistExample
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatButtonModule, 
    MatCheckboxModule, 
    MatTreeModule, 
    MatIconModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your index.html file

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```